# Cannot extropolate encryption techinque from this Hacker Rank challenge on Encryption

Tags: encryption

I am doing some Hacker Rank problems and I cannot figure out what the encryption method is in the challenge details, [here is the challenge.](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/encryption)

Excerpt from the challenge:

> The encoded message is obtained by displaying the characters in a column, inserting a space, and then displaying the next column and inserting a space, and so on. For example, the encoded message for the above rectangle is:
>
> ```
> imtgdvs fearwer mayoogo anouuio ntnnlvt wttddes aohghn sseoau
> ```

There is no mention of how the characters are changed to the output example the challenge provides...

I understand all elements of this question I think. The problem for me is: there is no details in the challenge about, after storing text in a grid, how the letters are encrypted.

Perhaps I am just very unfamiliar with encryption techniques and if I was more versed I could recognize some simple encryption pattern from the example output.

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: The grid is filled in row-major order and output in column-major order. [See this article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: or maybe it is programming question lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read it like this (concatenate marked letters):

`i`**m**tgdvs `f`**e**arwer `m`**a**yoogo `a`**n**ouuio `n`**t**nnlvt `w`**t**tddes `a`**o**hghn `s`**s**eoau

Then go back at the beginning and take the second letter from each word and so on.

`IfManWas` **MeantToS** ...

Comment: Geez, I see, I guess I need to drink some more coffee, man some of theses questions make me think I don't have the aptitude for coding and I been coding and doing good in the job world for almost 2 decades lol

Answer (score 0):

The approach as described in the problem, is to remove spaces and make a hole string. Then calculate the rows and cols and create a matrix multidimensional arre. Go through the string storing the chars in the matrix. Then reverse the matrix and create the final string.

```
static String encryption(String s) {

    String S = s.replace(" ", "");

    int L = S.length();
    int tryRow = (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(L));
    int row;
    int col = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(L));
    if (tryRow * col < L) {
        row = tryRow + 1;
    } else {
        row = tryRow;
    }
    char[][] matrix = IntStream.range(0, L).collect(
            () -> new char[row][col],
            (acc, i) -> {
                int r = i / col;
                int c = i - (r * col);
                acc[r][c] = S.charAt(i);
            },
            (a, b) -> {
            });
    char[][] temp = new char[col][row];
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            temp[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return Arrays.stream(temp)
            .map(arr -> String.valueOf(arr).trim())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```